# Getting the input from the output of this code

Tags: lua

I want to know the Opposite code to get the input from the output of this code
This script in converting "CODEXXXCODEXXX" To numbers, now while i have the numbers i want "CODEXXXCODEXXX" back. thanks in advance

```
local script = string.dump(
function()

-------------

--CODEXXXCODEXXX

-------------

end )

buff = ""

for v=1,string.len(script) do --Convert our string into a hex string.

     buff = buff..'\\'..string.byte(script,v)

end

file = io.open('encrypted.txt','w') --Output our bytecode into ascii format to encrypted.txt

file:write(buff)

file:flush()

file:close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the file and rebuild the string (note: use backslash as delimiter behind a number - not before)

```
script = "Hello World!"

buff = ""
for v=1,string.len(script) do --Convert our string into a [hex] byte string.
     buff = buff..string.byte(script,v)..'\\'
end

print(buff)

str_back = ""
for num in buff:gmatch("(%d+)\\") do
    str_back = str_back..string.char(num)
end

print(str_back)
```